# JQuery Infinite Loop for function

Tags: jquery

Here is a simple JQuery ticker I have written. How would I make it continue to tick after it gets to the end. At the moment it stops at the end of the sequence.

```
$('#fader').children().hide();

$.fn.seqfx = function() {

    $(this).fadeIn(400);
    $(this).delay(4000);
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).next().seqfx();

}); 
 };

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fader div:first").seqfx();
});
```

I tried `if ($(this).is('div:last')) { $(this).first().seqfx(); }; else $(this).next().seqfx();`

but it just repeats the first element constantly.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a better approach is to select all elements the trigger should rotate and then loop over the selected elements:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.seqfx = function() {
        var elements = this,
            l = elements.length,
            i = 0;

        function execute() {
            var current = $(elements[i]);
            i = (i + 1) % l;

            current
               .fadeIn(400)
               .delay(4000)
               .fadeOut(300, execute);
        }
        execute();
        return this;
    } ;
}(jQuery));
```

And then call it with

```
$("#fader div").seqfx();
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UHpbR/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function(){
      $("#fader div:first").seqfx();
    },4800);
});
```